# Does extern declaration on static function break internal linkage?

Tags: c, static, extern

I have a theoretical question.

Here's an example:

**file1.c**

```
static void foo()
{
    ...
}
```

**file2.c**

```
extern void foo(); 

main()
{
    foo();
}
```

The compilation is OK.

So, the extern breaks the internal linkage of static declaration?

Comment: What is surprising to you? The compiler works on one compilation unit at a time. The linker probably will complain.

Comment: Also, your `main` is not correct. It can accept arbitrary number of parameters.

Comment: Did you also try linking the program ?

Answer (score 4):

Is the "compilation ok" only in theory, or did you actually test this?

A `static` function should not be visible from outside the compilation unit (C file, typically) that it's in.

Declaring a function of the same name with `extern` in a different compilation unit should not change this.

Make sure you really build and *link* the test program properly, since otherwise all that you're testing is that you can have a "dangling" reference to an external symbol (the `foo` function referenced from 2.c). Building 2.c into an executable (i.e. linking it) should fail.

Answer (score 0):

The compilation should be OK. If you can also link that, your compiler have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

A quick test confirms the expected linker failure (VC++ 2010 express):

1>test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl foo(void)" (?foo@@YAXXZ) referenced in function _wmain